# The value of the property "BaseIntermediateOutputPath" was modified after it was used by MSBuild. I keep getting this warning but I don't know why

Tags: msbuild

I keep getting this warning but I don't know why.

> The value of the property "BaseIntermediateOutputPath" was modified after it was used by MSBuild which can lead to unexpected build results. Tools such as NuGet will write outputs to the path specified by the "MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath" instead. To set this property, you must do so before Microsoft.Common.props is imported, for example by using Directory.Build.props. For more information, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=869650

It's code is MSB3539.

I have read that article in link, and I have created `Directory.Build.props` file in my solution directory, in which I have specified property

```xml
<MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath>$(SolutionDir)artifacts\$(MSBuildProjectName)\$(Configuration)</MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath>
```

But I still getting this warning. What am I doing wrong? Solution builds, every file is placed correctly. But it's kind of annoying.

Project is .NET 7.0 class library..

Comment: The error message is about `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` being modified. Is the value of `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` being changed in the project file?

Comment: Hi, I have changed BaseIntermediateOutputPath value in my .csproj file from $(ProjectDir)obj to $(SolutionDir)artifacts\$(AssemblyName).. Even if I hard code value to my desired path I still got this warning. When I checked Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets file and line that throws that warning I have understand that this warning is thrown when it's enabled && InitialPath' != Path && Path != MSBuildPath (I have shortened names of properties..). Seems to me that solution is to change value of $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) in Microsoft.Common.props. But I don't want to do that.

Comment: The warning is because you are changing `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` within the body of the project file. Move the modification of `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` from the project file to the `Directory.Build.props` file. `Directory.Build.props` is imported before `Microsoft.Common.props`. Don't change `MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath`.

Comment: Thanks. I reposted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The warning is because `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` is changed within the body of the project file.

Move the modification of `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` from the project file to the `Directory.Build.props` file. `Directory.Build.props` is imported before `Microsoft.Common.props`.

Don't change `MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath`.

Comment: Is this a workaround for a bug? Why does the VS IDE offer "Base intermediate output path" as a property to change and then report an error if one changes it?

Comment: It is not a workaround for a bug. You can change `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` but it must be modified very early in the evaluation phase before `Microsoft.Common.props`. The MSB3539 error is reporting that custom code that has been added to the project has a bug.

Comment: Yes, I've used BaseIntermediateOutputPath in a Directory.Build.props file with no problem for years. However, when I set it directly in the project via the IDE, the aforementioned error message is displayed. Obviously, this is a bug in the IDE, because if setting BaseIntermediateOutputPath in the csproj file is problematic, then the IDE shouldn't offer it as a property to be changed - the IDE should at least make it a read-only property. Haven't you ever seen "Peanuts" cartoon where Lucy tells Charlie Brown to kick the football, then pulls it away as he kicks it? - that's what the IDE does.

Comment: Oh. I didn't realize that you were talking about the project properties windows in the IDE. Yes, it's a bug that the IDE is setting the property in the .csproj file which is the wrong place to do that. The IDE project properties window probably shouldn't show the property at all. Note that the `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` property is something that MSBuild defines and owns, not the IDE.

Comment: Yes, thank you! We could code name the bug "Lucy" :-)

Comment: I created a [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/BUG:-C-Project-Properties-window-supp/10475914).

Answer (score 2):

Addition to @Jonathan Dodds' answer, you create the `Directory.Build.props` file yourself in the root-folder of your project.

Content:

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>obj_new</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: `Directory.Build.props` and `Directory.Build.targets` can be in the project folder or any parent folder. MSBuild will search up the directory hierarchy for the files.